# Laravel - Eloquent return only one value

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

How can I return one value from a belongsToMany relation.

This is my relation:

```
public function role() {

    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Role');

}
```

Now when I want to access the Role Name I have to do the folowing:

```
Auth::user()->role[0]->name
```

But I just want to do

```
Auth::user()->role
```

But now my question is: "How can I do that?"

Comment: You can't, the `user()` doesn't directly know about what is inside of `role` therefore you need to have `role` there. What you could do however it create a method on the `User` class which has a helper method like `getRole()`. Also instead of using array syntax to get the first result, you can just do `Auth::user()->role()->first()->name`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

to do this you need add custom attribute to user model as the following:

User Model:

```
protected $appends = ['role'];  // add new attribute to user model

public function getRoleAttribute()
{
   return $this->roles->first(); // don't use roles() it would execute every time  
}

public function roles() {
return $this->belongsToMany('App\Role');
}
```

now you can use

```
Auth::user()->role
```

Comment: Ah, okay, nice. This works exactly as I hoped it did. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
Auth::user()->role()->first()
```

Besides the question itself, i suggest you to use the plural name for belogsToMany relations: it is a common best practice and makes the code much more expressive.

```
public function roles() {
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Role');
}

Auth::user()->roles()->first()
```

Comment: Yes, this kind of works. I now can do `Auth::user()->roles()` Still don't really like the `()` would like to get rid of those, but if it's not really possible am I fine with it. thanks.