# Appending Eloquent Attributes/Modified Relation Date on Query Building / Code Optimization

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.5

I'm looking for a solution to optimize my Code using Laravel Eloquent.

My issue is that I want to add Attributes conditionally, and this Attributes is basically the a transformed many-to-many relationship.

At the moment I have this in my controller (simplified):

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controller;

/**
 * Class Category
 */
class Category extends Controller
{

    /**
     * @return Collection
     */
    public function index()
    {
        return Category::withCount('countries')->get();
    }

    /**
     * @param int $id
     *
     * @return Category
     */
    public function show($id)
    {
        $result = Category::where('id', $id)
            ->with('countries')
            ->firstOrFail();

        $result->countries_list = '';

        return $result;
    }
}
```

My Category model looks like this (simplified):

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

/**
 * Class Category
 */
class Category extends Model
{

    /**
     * The accessors to append to the model's array form.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $appends = [

    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'countries',
    ];

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getCountriesCountAttribute()
    {
        return trans_choice('labels.countries', $this->original['countries_count']);
    }

    /**
     * @return
     */
    public function getCountriesListAttribute()
    {
        return $this->countries->pluck('alpha_2');
    }

    /**
     * Get the related Countries.
     */
    public function countries()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(
            Country::class,
            'category_country',
            'category_id',
            'country_id'
        );
    }
}
```

The Country Model is just a list of Countries with id, name, the Alpha2 Code, etc. I can't use the protected $appends to add countries_list because than the the list would be always included.
I also can't change my Countries model because this is used in several other occurrences.

What I'm looking for is a way to optimize the code in the controller to this:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controller;

/**
 * @return Collection
 */
public function index()
{
    return Category::withCount('countries')->get();
}

/**
 * @param int $id
 *
 * @return Category
 */
public function show($id)
{
    return Category::where('id', $id)
        ->withAttribute('countries_list') // An array of all country aplha 2 codes
        ->firstOrFail();
}
```

Comment: i think this example will help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44070497/laravel-eloquent-return-only-one-value/44071133#44071133

Comment: No this is not what I whan. Please read the Question!

Comment: Isn't lazy loading related models what you are looking for?

Answer (score -1):

You can access the `countries_list` attribute after querying (don't include it **in** your query).

```
public function show($id)
{
    $category = Category::findOrFail($id);

    $list = $category->countries_list; // this calls getCountriesListAttribute()
}
```